# network provider work only with location enabled?

Tags: android, location

Do i need to enable location in setting for getting location based on network provider? If i had wifi enable :

`locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` - false

and if i had location enable (whatever is wifi) :

`locationMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` - true

how can i get the location with location disable and wifi enable ?

I work on android api 23

thank you, and sorry for my english, i hope you understand

LATER EDIT:
this is my manifest
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".WeatherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".WeatherActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".WeatherActivity" />
    </activity>


    <service
        android:name=".background.ControlService"
        android:enabled="true" />
</application>
```

`

Comment: Does your wifi connection has internet access? And post the permissions you've granted in manifest for this.

Comment: yes the device has internet acces and this is from log  (press location button on phone)`04-04 **13:03:35.055** 6021-6021/com.example.catalin.licenta_ultimate E/BOOMB: onProviderDisabled: network \n
04-04 **13:03:35.056** 6021-6021/com.example.catalin.licenta_ultimate E/BOOMB: onProviderDisabled: gps \n  (press location button  again) \n
04-04 **13:03:44.702** 6021-6021/com.example.catalin.licenta_ultimate E/BOOMB: onProviderEnabled: network \n
04-04 **13:03:44.723** 6021-6021/com.example.catalin.licenta_ultimate E/BOOMB: onProviderEnabled: gps` look at the seconds      @fluffyBatman

Comment: same problem, you found solution?